# wp_logout_url not working

Tags: wordpress, logout

I am currently building a website on WordPress. I have a Logout link (within .. tags). When the user clicks on that it should logout and redirect to the current page.

I have used :

```
 <a id="logout-submit" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink());?>">Log Out</a>
```

But that does not seem to work properly. When I click on the link, nothing happens. When I Right-click on the link and open in a new tab, the user is logged out. Please tel me how I should go about correcting this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any domain or redirect plugins?

Comment: Hi Andy, Thank you for the response.  I am building the website in my local machine. I am not using any redirect plugins. What is going wrong here?

Comment: If you remove the get_permalink function from the logout function what happens?  What is the URL that gets wrote to the anchor link when the get_permalink function is in there?  Your line of code is correct, so I'm just trying to do a little troubleshooting here.

Answer (score 2):

use something like that:

```
<?php echo wp_logout_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); ?>
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a id="logout-submit" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url();?>">Log Out</a>
```

Comment: It works. Try it outside the script where it fails. The problem might be with that script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good point to consider when using get_permalink(); Note that when used outside The Loop on a posts page (index, archive, etc.) without the ID parameter, it will return the URL of the last post in The Loop, not the permalink for the current page. - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

I am also using: `<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url();?>">Log Out</a>`. It is properly echoing the correct logout url but instead of logging me out I get the white screen of death. This is not a pulgin issue and it only occurs when trying to log out (no matter where I try to log out).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:  RA_Cikis_Yap
File:           RA_Cikis_Yap.php
Site:           RanaAJANS.com
User:           Rana ERDOĞAN & Ümüt DEMİR
Date:           2020.04.20 20:20:20
Page properties -> Template -> RA_Cikis_Yap.php
*/

session_start();
ob_start();
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
#    echo $user_id."<br>";
#    echo "<pre>";
#    var_dump(is_user_logged_in());
#    echo "</pre>";    
wp_logout();
session_unset();
session_destroy(); 
wp_destroy_current_session();
wp_clear_auth_cookie();
wp_set_current_user( 0 );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'session_tokens', mb_strtoupper(bin2hex(random_bytes(20))) ); # Generate random 40 character value
//wp_redirect(site_url());

header( "Refresh: 3; url= ".home_url()."/iletisim/" );
// echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3; url=https://RanaAJANS.com/iletisim/'>";  
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>   
<style>
.swal-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
.swal-modal {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.99);
  border: 3px solid white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  swal({
          type: 'error',
          icon: "warning",
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: 'Çıkış Yaptınız!',
          button: "Tamam",
          className: "swal-overlay",
          closeModal: false  
        })
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Please add some context to help understand the answer.